# CGAffineTransformRotate to rotate number of times rather then to an angle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

This seems to rotate to an angle not by an amount. I need to use this within a UIView animation to rotate an image view several times over itself. Any alternative?

`CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 1.0);`

Answer (score 7):

The rotation transform rotates by a given angle, but I guess you're trying to achieve a 360 degree (or more) rotation. To do this you'll need to use a `CAAnimation` to achieve it... Example:

```
CABasicAnimation* spinAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
spinAnimation.duration = 5.0;
spinAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
spinAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2.0 * M_PI * 20.0];
[myView.layer addAnimation:spinAnimation forKey:@"spinAnimation"];
```

The code above will rotate myView 20 times in 5 seconds

Comment: This is not quite what he is asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is that the parameter to CGAffineTransformRotate is expected in radians and not 'count of rotations.'  Thankfully, it's easy enough to convert from 'count of rotations' to radians by multiplying by (2.0 * M_PI).

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But it still doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Ah... you mean that CGAffineTransformRotate seems to normalize down to a range of -2pi < X < 2pi. Mmph. I suspect you're probably going to need to do something akin to what @AshleyMills suggested, but if that proposal doesn't work out of the box you might try doing it in stages, with one rotation per "stage".

Comment: Yeah, @AshleyMills' approach works right, out of the box for me. Is SimonLee right in that that is somehow not what you were asking?

Answer (score -1):

You need to preserve the current transform and rotate AGAIN... so you need...

```
[myView setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(myView.transform, 1.0)];
```

This will apply the rotation to any existing transform, initially this will be CGAffineTransformIdentity, which is no rotation, scale or translation.

Comment: Applying CGAffineTransformRotate multiple times still normalizes to a range of -2pi < X < 2pi. For example: this doesn't work.

        CGAffineTransform originalTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        originalTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(originalTransform, (CGFloat) (M_PI));
        originalTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(originalTransform, (CGFloat) (M_PI));